# Even after converting my variable into factors , upon running the contrasts function, it says "contrasts apply only to factors"

Tags: r

After I repeatedly got the error, "contrasts apply only to factors", I converted a column of variables into factors using the `as.factor` function, and still the same error shows up.

Here's the code(running the `contrasts` function both ways: my installation of R has only the `contrasts()` functions, not `contrast()`) :

```
x <- as.factor(spider$leg)
contrasts(fit,list(spider$legL4),list(spider$legL2))
```

> Error in contrasts(fit, list(spider$legL4), list(spider$legL2)) : contrasts apply only to factors

```
L4vsL2 <- `contrasts<-`(fit, list(leg="L4"),list(leg="L2"))
```

> Error in `contrasts<-`(fit, list(leg = "L4"), list(leg = "L2")) :  contrasts apply only to factors

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please help us to help you by making your question reproducible; here's a good guide: [reprex]. Ideally including a sample of your input data provided as an object e.g. `df <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b=4:5)` or use `dput(df)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've got here so far doesn't make much sense. I'm not sure why you're trying to apply contrasts to something called `fit`, which is probably (?) a fitted statistical model. Try something like:

```
spider$legL4 <- as.factor(spider$legL4)
contrasts(spider$legL4) <- contr.sum(length(levels(spider$legL4)))
```

would work (then you have to re-fit your model to use the new contrasts).

Comment: I figured out another way to get my contrasts - by changing the level of the data that I'm comparing to the values of my interest. However, I ran this code and fit y model again and that worked too!